# Can two people play each other's shared Steam games?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

If both me and my friend are sharing each others libraries, can I play a game from his library while he is playing one from mine?

Answer (score 7):

With Steam Family Sharing, you're sharing your entire library at once, meaning that if someone is playing a game from your library, nobody else can access any game from that same library. If you're playing a game from your friend's library, your friend is free to play any games from your library, as your library is not in use while playing your friend's game.

Comment: Did you test this? From my experience the sharing was blocked from my friend when I was playing -any- steam game.

Comment: I've had the same experience as @InfernoIV.

Comment: Yes, this has always worked for me.